# JMapper XML configuration for extended classes

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, configuration, mapping

I want to configure the xml file to map to an extended class, but get an UndefinedMappingException. The only related topic I can find is [this](https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core/wiki/Inheritance-examples)

Here's my implementation:

```
JMapper<RequestD, RequestS> mapper =
            new JMapper<>(RequestD.class, RequestS.class, "jmapper.xml");
    RequestD requestD = mapper.getDestination(someRequestS);
```

Destination class:

```
public class RequestD extends RequestBase {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Extended Class:

```
public abstract class RequestBase implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Language language;
private DateTime requestDateTime;
private String currency;
private Order order;

/**
 * Getters and Setters 
 */
```

Source class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RequestS")
public class RequestS {

    @Valid
    protected Language language;
    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected DateTime requestDateTime;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    protected Order order;

/**
 * Getters and Setters  
 */
```

jmapper.xml:

```
<jmapper>
    <class name="package.RequestD">
        <attribute name="language">
            <value name="language"/>
        </attribute>
    </class>
</jmapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UndefinedMappingException is thrown because the attribute **language** doesn't exist in the destination class **RequestD** and you shouldn't try to map this.

Instead configure the destination class to use the global mapping facility:

```
<jmapper>
    <class name="package.RequestD">
        <global/>
    </class>
</jmapper>
```

This will allow the extended class to be found for mapping.

*Note:* You should provide configuration for every destination class where you want to map an attribute. The example below includes attributes that weren't shown above, but makes a more complete example:

```
<jmapper>
    <class name="package.RequestD">
        <global/>
    </class>

    <class name="package.Language">
        <attribute name="name">
            <value name="name"/>
        </attribute>
    </class>

    <class name="package.Order">
        <attribute name="number">
            <value name="number"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="reference">
            <value name="reference"/>
        </attribute>
    </class>
</jmapper>
```